# Disable Intellij from adding <p> to my empty comment lines

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have to add a copyright comment to every java file within my project which looks like this:

```
/**
 * Some text
 *
 * Some more text
 */
```

Everytime I run reformat with Intellij it changes into

```
/**
 * Some text
 * <p>
 * Some more text
 */
```

Is it possible to disable adding `<p>` into every empty comment line?

Comment: why not ask the intelliJ commynity? You didn't even mention how you put the text now, so how are we supposed to (even) guess how to improve your current approach?

Comment: @Stultuske This happens when you type a comment at the top of a class and reformat - IntelliJ adds these, presumably so the generated JavaDoc formats correctly. It does look awful though.

Comment: Note that your copyright should not live in `/**  ...  */`. That format marks the comment as a Javadoc comment, which subjects it to all sorts of rules & constraints, including where it should/can be placed and the format it should take. Instead, change it to `/*`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Go to File -> Settings -> Editor -> Code Style -> Java -> JavaDoc tab, and then uncheck `Generate "<p>" on empty lines`